# visitor visa for Canada: proof of relationship for inviting family friend

Tags: visas, canada

I'm doing the visitor visa application on behalf of my Aunt. It's the first time of mine.
My Aunt family friend has invited her for his son's wedding. The family friend has provided all the necessary documents.

Questions are below:

1- How can we proof the relationship of family friend.

2- My Aunt is housemaker and 56 years old, doesn't have the property under her name, doesn't have good funds to show off. Hence, for that she has open the join account with her husband.

3- Does the ITR or taxes payment receipt is require to show with the application ?

Please  do advise some plus points to make the file bit stronger

Comment: Referring to your Question 2: I'm afraid a new joint bank account may be seen as sudden access to money, as in "Funds Parking," as discussed [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). You might also review the "Funds Parking, Lifestyle, and Credibility" and "Provenance of Funds" sections [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e). Both cited questions refer to the UK, but Canadian analysis is apt to be similar.

Answer (score 6):

1. You probably don't need to provide proof of relationship. It's entirely reasonable for a family friend to be invited to a wedding. Including names of the people being married and details of the wedding, to prove it is really happening, is probably helpful.
2. Your aunt needs to state that her husband is paying for the trip (assuming he is). She needs to include her husband's financial details, including bank statements, to prove that he can afford to pay for her, and also a statement by him that he will be paying. It is not necessary for there to be a joint account. It's very common that husbands pay for their wife's trip when she isn't financially independent and this won't negatively impact the application. (Your aunt should also provide any financial information about herself that she can.)
3. Her husband needs to provide enough financial information to prove that he can afford to pay, just as if he was applying himself. Tax statements might be part of that, but bank account details showing cashflow details are much better.

Comment: One thing I would be concerned about is "ties to home country".  Yes, "husband paying for trip" is likely fairly strong, but anything to make it clear that she intends to return (and won't try to stay with 'family friend' after the wedding) would help.  But I haven't had to deal with this as any part of the exchange, I'm just parroting what people say here and elsewhere.  Is this something that should be added?